# Позиционирование div (не получается)

Tags: html, css, display, inline

Имеются три div блока. Выровнял по линии их с помощью display: inline-block. Но мне нужно один элемент, который посередине подвинуть немного вниз (выделен на скриншоте).. margin-top не работает, а точнее двигает все три блока вниз.. Помогите решить..

[image: Скриншот]

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
  src: url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('../fonts/RobotoSlabBold.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
body {
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-family: 'Roboto Slab';
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: normal;
 width: 100%;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
     /* Header*/
header {
 width: 1350px;
 height: 100px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 font-weight: bold;
}
header li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-top: 20px;

}
header a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
.header__feedback {
 float: right;
 width: 200px;
 height: 80px;
 font-size: 21px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.header__logo {
 display: inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 10px;
}
.header__menu_list {
 display: inline-block;
}
.header__feedback_icon img {
 width: 20px;
 float: left;
 margin-top: 9px;
 margin-left: 4px;
}
.header__feedback_items {
 font-size: 14px;
 width: 156px;
 height: 38px;
 border: 1px solid #2f1059;
 border-radius: 5px;
 line-height: 38px;
 margin-top: 8px;
 margin-left: 25px;
}
.header__feedback_button a {
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.header__feedback_number {
 color: #2f1059;
}
.header__menu_list_item1 {
 margin-left: 50px;
}
.header__menu_list_item2,
.header__menu_list_item3,
.header__menu_list_item4,
.header__menu_list_item5 {
 margin-left: 20px;
}
     /* Header END*/
     /* Section1*/
section {
 width: 1920px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
}
.section1 {
 background: url('../img/background.jpg') no-repeat center top scroll;
 padding: 1px;
 min-height: 600px;
}
.section1__heading_paragraph_up {
 font-size: 22px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin-top: -10px;
 margin-left: 15px;
} 
.section1__heading_paragraph_down {
 font-size: 20px;
 margin-top: -30px;
}
.section1__heading {
 text-align: center;
 margin-top: 75px;
 color: #2f1059;
}
.section1__heading h1 {
 font-size: 43px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin-top: -20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
.section1__head {
 width: 1350px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
    /* form*/
.form {
 background: url(../img/form.png) no-repeat center top;
 width: 920px;
 height: 378px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 165px auto 0 auto;
 padding-top: 100px;
}
.form__head {
 font-size: 24px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fbfafa;
}
.form__head p {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 17px;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.form__block {
 margin-top: 27px;
}
.form__input1 {
 width: 201px;
 height: 51px;
 border: 0px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #fff;
}
.form__input2 {
 width: 201px;
 height: 51px;
 border: 0px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-color: #fff;
 margin-left: 7px;
}
.form__button {
 width: 274px;
 height: 51px;
 background: #d22828;
 color: #fff;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 17px;
 border: 0px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 margin-left: 7px;
}
.form__footer {
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: normal;
 color: #7925ec;
 margin-top: 40px;
}
.form__footer span {
 width: 27px;
 height: 27px;
 font-size: 21px;
 font-weight: bold;
 border: 1px solid #7925ec;
 border-radius: 3px;
 padding: 0 8px;
}

     /* form END*/
     /* Преимущества*/

.advantages ul {
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 1350px;
 height: 150px;
}
.advantages li {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 display: block;
 float: left;
 background: url(../img/ellipse.png) no-repeat;
 background-size: 153px;
 width: 153px;
 height: 153px;
 font-size: 17px;
 padding: 32px 0;
 font-weight: normal;
 text-align: center;
 margin-right: 45px;
}
.advantages__list span {
 font-size: 16px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
.advantages__item1 {
 margin-left: 75px;
}
.advantages li:nth-child(3), .advantages li:nth-child(4) {
 margin-top: -135px;
}
.advantages li:nth-child(2), .advantages li:nth-child(5) {
 margin-top: -68px;
}
.clearfix:after {
 content: '';
 display: table;
 width: 100%;
 clear: both;
}
     /* Преимущества END*/
     /* Section1 END*/
     /* Section2*/

.section2 {
 background: url(../img/background2.png) no-repeat;
 min-height: 200px;
 margin-top: 25px;
 padding: 1px;
}
.section2 h2 {
 margin: 20px 0 10px 0;
}
.section2__block {
 width: 1350px;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.section2__head {
 font-size: 30px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: #fff;
}
.section2__head p {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 margin: 0;
}
.section2__head_ellipse {
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.section2__location {
 margin: 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
.section2__location_heading {
 width: 1350px;
 margin: 39px auto 0 auto;
 text-align: center;
}
.section2__location_heading h2 {
 font-size: 37px;
 font-weight: bold;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.section2__location_heading p {
 font-size: 20px;
 font-weight: normal;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 16px 0 0 0;
}
.section2__location_items {
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-weight: normal;
}
.section2__location_item span {
 font-size: 21px;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Тренировка</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:100,300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
 <header>
  <nav>
   <div class="header__logo">
    <img src="img/logo2.png" alt="Logo">
   </div>
   <div class="header__menu_list">
    <ul>
     <li class="header__menu_list_item1"><a href="#">Инфраструктура</a></li>
     <li class="header__menu_list_item2"><a href="#">Планировки и цены</a></li>
     <li class="header__menu_list_item3"><a href="#">Материалы и отделка</a></li>
     <li class="header__menu_list_item4"><a href="#">Документы</a></li>
     <li class="header__menu_list_item5"><a href="#">Контакты</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="header__feedback">
    <div class="header__feedback_number">
     + 7 (495) 544-23-12
    </div>
    <div class="header__feedback_items">
      <div class="header__feedback_icon">
        <img src="img/icon_phone.png" alt="icon">
      </div>
      <div class="header__feedback_button"> 
        <a href="#">Заказать звонок</a>
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>
 </header>
 <section class="section1">
  <div class="section1__head">
   <div class="section1__heading">
    <p class="section1__heading_paragraph_up">
    <span>Дом готов</span> идет внутренняя отделка. Срок сдачи: <span>Февраль 2016</span>
    </p>
    <h1>Ваша квартира в новостройке ждет вас</h1>
    <p class="section1__heading_paragraph_down">Уютные квартиры в центре города и в <span>5 минутых от р. Волга</span></p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form">
   <div class="form__head">
    Запишитесь на просмотр прямо сейчас!
    <p>
    Покажем Вам квартиры в удобное для Вас время
    </p>
   </div>
   <form class="form__block" action="#">
    <input class="form__input1" type="text" method "post" placeholder="Имя">
    <input class="form__input2" type="tel" method "post" placeholder="Телефон">
    <button class="form__button" type="submit">Записаться на просмотр!</button>
   </form>
   <div class="form__footer">Осталось всего <span>5</span> квартир!</div>
  </div>
  <div class="advantages">
   <ul class="advantages__list clearfix">
    <li class="advantages__item1"><span>5 минут</span> до центра</li>
    <li class="advantages__item2"><span>300 метров</span> до Волги</li>
    <li class="advantages__item3"><span>Экологически чистое</span> место</li>
    <li class="advantages__item4"><span>Бесплатная кладовка</span> в подвале</li>
    <li class="advantages__item5"><span>Бесплатное парковочное место</span></li>
    <li class="advantages__item"><span>Бюджетная отделка под ключ</span> въехал и живи</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </section>
 <section class="section2">
  <div class="section2__block">
   <div class="section2__head">
    <h2>Дом готов. Идет внутренняя отделка</h2>
    <p>
     <img src="img/icon.png" alt="icon">
     Срок сдачи: Февраль 2016
    </p>
   </div>
   <div class="section2__head_ellipse">
    <img src="img/ellipse2.png" alt="png">
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="section2__location">
  <div class="section2__location_heading">
   <h2>ИДЕАЛЬНОЕ РАСПОЛОЖЕНИЕ ДОМА</h2>
   <p>тихий и экологически чистый район</p>
  </div>
  <div class="section2__location_item">
    <div class="section2__location_items">
     <img src="img/river.png" alt="#">
     <div class="section2__location_items_text">
      <span>Близость к реке</span><br>
      До волги 300 метров
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section2__location_items section2__location_items_old">
     <img src="img/green_zone.png" alt="#">
     <div class="section2__location_items_text">
      <span>Зеленые зоны</span><br>
      Березовая роща и сосновый бор
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="section2__location_items">
     <img src="img/atmo.png" alt="#">
     <div class="section2__location_items_text">
      <span>Соседи и атмосфера</span><br>
      Коттеджи деревенская застройка вокруг
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте vertical-align:top; к .section2__location_items

Comment: Спасибо, получилось!

Answer (score 0):

Всем трем блокам с изображениями - position: relative; Второму блоку    section2:nth-child(2){top:20px;}